# Install Powershell for Azure without an Azure Account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I want to use Get-AzureStorageBlob  in a powershell script so my client can download files from my Azure Blob storage ( I use Devops to put them there )

The keys are in the script so the client does not need an Azure account.

He does however need to install [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.3.0)

And the instructions ask him to log in to Azure.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.3.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just operates with azure storage, then you can ignore the "Connect-AzAccount" cmdlet.

After installing azure powershell module, since you have account_name and account_key of storage account, directly use them to download the blob.

But if you want to operate other resources like vm etc.,then you need to the cmdlet "Connect-AzAccount".

When I click Show Details in the right Commands panel I get an error message

```
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
```

Comment: However Get-AzuureStorageBlob is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: I see that in your mentioned doc, you installed use this line of code "Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber"? right?

Comment: yes thats right, running Powershell 5.1 as administrator.

Comment: What you installed is actually the new azure powershell module, you should use the new cmdlet which built in the Az Module. In your case, you should use [Get-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-1.3.0) instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703271/get-command-the-term-get-azstorageblobcontent-is-not-recognized-as-the-name