# Get-Command : The term 'Get-AzStorageBlobContent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

From [my question about installing Azure Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701405/install-powershell-for-azure-without-an-azure-account/54702443?noredirect=1#comment96192468_54702443)
I was able to install Azure Powershell 5.1

However when I try to run

```
Get-Command Get-AzStorageBlobContent
```

I get

```
Get-Command : The term 'Get-AzStorageBlobContent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Command Get-AzStorageBlobContent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzStorageBlobContent:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

I can see the commands listed in the right panel of ISE and I get intellisence help
[image: error message]

The link [135170 takes me here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

returns Restricted

Comment: Does this issue occurs on the local pc? or only occurs in devops?

Comment: local pc, sorry for not saying that.

Comment: Try : https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/

Comment: That worked @JoyWang Care to modify your answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` as administrator to fix the issue.

See: https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/